# type.__new__() takes exactly 3 arguments (0 given)

Tags: python, class

I am learning python, I found something interesting with class.

In python docs, the classes are inherited from types, so i think

```
class person(type):
    name = 'kevin'
p = person()
print(p.name)
```

should be same with

```
class person:
    name = 'kevin'
```

but actually running first code, I got mistake

```
TypeError: type.__new__() takes exactly 3 arguments (0 given)
```

running the second code no mistake, can anyone explain ? thank you`

Comment: Did you look up `type` and how to use it? `person` is a *metaclass*. But there is no need for it, you can just use `type` directly but it requires three arguments... again, look it up in the docs... but here: `person = type('person', (object,), {'name':kevin})` would create the equivalent class object as your class definition statement

Comment: Your first and second code is not the same, inheriting from `object` would give the desired behavior you are looking for. Inheriting from `type` makes it a metaclass.

Comment: Understood, type is a metaclass, a method used to create class manually, than you!

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting from `type` makes it a metaclass. Remove `type` as the Base class.

```
class person():
    name = 'kevin'
p = person()
print(p.name)

> kevin
```